# Is there a way to check if a variable is an instance of an inner class whose outer class is a certain class?

Tags: python, class, parent

example code:

```
class A:
    class B:
        def __init__(self):
            pass

var = A.B()
```

i need a function, let's say `check_if_class_parent(obj, class_type)` that would check if `var` is an instance of an inner class whose outer class is `A`, which if i run `check_if_class_parent(var, A)`, it would return `True`

sometimes the class structure could be like this:

```
class A:
    class B:
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        
        class C:
            def __init__(self):
                pass

var = A.B.C()
var_two = A.B()
```

`check_if_class_parent(var, A)`, `check_if_class_parent(var, B)`, and `check_if_class_parent(var_two, A)` would all return `True`, but `check_if_class_parent(var, C)` would return `False`

Comment: Those are nested classes, not child classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. An `outer` attribute could be added to the inner classes, in which case it's just a matter of walking up any `outer` attributes found on a value's type to see if `A` can be reached. However this does add extra definitions.
2. A search can be conducted starting from `A`. E.g. (and not accounting for any dastardly cyclic references at all):

```
def is_type_within(obj, type_):
    if isinstance(obj, type_):
        return True
    for attr in dir(type_):
        if attr.startswith('__'):
            continue
        if is_type_within(obj, getattr(type_, attr)):
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Question was a bit inconsistent on whether to include `A` or only inner classes so the first check might have to be changed around